# указатель на функцию в качестве параметра

Tags: c++, функции

Функция GetDataFromServer принимает в качестве параметра какую-то строчку и её возвращает. Функция GetDataFromBase делает то же самое. Функция ShowInfo принимает в качестве параметра указатель на функцию с 1 параметром типа string и должна её вызвать в cout, но как это сделать(подскажите что не так в коде)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string GetDataFromServer(string DataServer)
{
    return DataServer;
}

string GetDataFromBase(string DataBD)
{
    return DataBD;
}

void ShowInfo(string(*foo)(string data))
{
    cout << foo(data) << endl;
}
int main()
{
    string Data = "data is 8";
    ShowInfo(GetDataFromBase(Data));
}
```

Comment: Вы передаёте не функцию, а строку; результат выполнения функции

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь

```
void ShowInfo(string(*foo)(string data))
```

`data` не играет никакой роли - как в объявлении функции.

```
void ShowInfo(string(*foo)(string), string data)
```

еще куда ни шло. Ну, и вызывать соответственно -

```
ShowInfo(GetDataFromBase,Data);
```